# Text file is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make an application which will monitor specific folder and if text file appears there it should open the file, do something for each line in that file and then delete that file and wait for another one. I have acomplished just about everything, except i get error that my file is in use by another process,

This is my code:

```
  Public Function startSrvc()
    watchfolder = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()
    watchfolder.Path = txtDirToWatch.Text
    watchfolder.NotifyFilter = IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
    watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchfolder.NotifyFilter Or
                       IO.NotifyFilters.FileName
    watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchfolder.NotifyFilter Or
                       IO.NotifyFilters.Attributes
    AddHandler watchfolder.Created, AddressOf logchange
    watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Function

    Private Sub logchange(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As _
                    System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
    If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created Then
        print(e.FullPath.ToString)
    End If
End Sub

Public Function print(ByVal path As String)

    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
    For Each line As String In lines

    Next
  My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(path)
End Function
```

I get error

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'E:\\testprint\test - Copy.txt' because it is being used by another process.
```

on this line `Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)`.

The first time i create file in the folder my application completes everything successfully, it reads the file and then deletes it. After that if i create another file the program breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `FileSystemWatcher` is not always as easy as you might think. If you are detecting `Created` changes then you will detect the moment that a new file is created, while the file content is written for some time after that, which would explain why your file is in use. I had an application that created a file with one component and detected it using a `FileSystemWatcher` in another and I wrote it using a temporary extension and then renamed it. I then detected `Renamed` changes and had no issues. If this is not an option, you may need to just check the file periodically until it is available.